# Low Probability Estimate from Cumulative Frequency Histogram

Tags: probability, histogram

I've fitted a 3-parameter Weibull distribution into a sample size of $N=31392$ using Maximum Likelihood Estimation. I'm comparing exceedance probability estimates with the data's cumulative frequency histogram:

[image: Comparison within the domain of validity]

Trouble is, I've noticed there's a 'lift-off' effect of the cumulative histogram at the tail-end, which become more pronounced at even lower probabilities, hence deviating away from the Weibull description:

[image]

My question is, is the data's cumulative frequency histogram still representative of the true probability of non-exceedance? If not, how can I adjust the data's description to counter this 'lift-off' effect?

Comment: One thing you could do is simulate samples of the size of your original, from sets of parameters like your fitted three parameter Weibull a bunch of times each (like say 10 -- or more) and look at the equivalent plot (compared to its  as if it were a new sample of real data (with a new ML fit for it). If you sometimes see a similar pattern it's probably not signifying anything but noise. If you never see a pattern like this it may well indicate a problem with the model.